# Xml parsing having two namespaces

Tags: c#, xml, serialization

I am working on xml parsing. 
My xml doc is

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<BCPFORMAT 
xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/sqlserver/2004/bulkload/format" 
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
  <RECORD>
    <FIELD ID="1" xsi:type="CharTerm" TERMINATOR="\t" 
      MAX_LENGTH="12"/> 
    <FIELD ID="2" xsi:type="CharTerm" TERMINATOR="\t" 
      MAX_LENGTH="20" COLLATION="SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS"/>
    <FIELD ID="3" xsi:type="CharTerm" TERMINATOR="\r\n" 
      MAX_LENGTH="30" 
      COLLATION="SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS"/>
  </RECORD>
  <ROW>
    <COLUMN SOURCE="1" NAME="age" xsi:type="SQLINT"/>
    <COLUMN SOURCE="2" NAME="firstname" xsi:type="SQLVARYCHAR"/>
    <COLUMN SOURCE="3" NAME="lastname" xsi:type="SQLVARYCHAR"/>
  </ROW>
</BCPFORMAT>
```

Please help me in parsing this doc.

Comment: Just use an XmlDocument or XDocument.

Comment: into what do you want to parse it? what would be your output?

Comment: thats great, that you want to parse it, but what are you going to do with it after you do that? You can use XElement.Parse() to turn it into an XElement?

Comment: What's giving you problems at the moment? LINQ to XML has great namespace support.

Answer (score 0):

The standard way of parsing a small-ish xml document like this is to the use [`XmlDocument`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.xmldocument.aspx) class.  To get you started, if the xml document is contained in a file "test.xml" you can use the following:

```
XmlDocument doc = new XmlDocument();
doc.Load("test.xml");

XmlNamespaceManager nsmgr = new XmlNamespaceManager(doc.NameTable);
nsmgr.AddNamespace("bulk", "http://schemas.microsoft.com/sqlserver/2004/bulkload/format");

XmlElement fieldElement = (XmlElement)doc.SelectSingleNode("bulk:BCPFORMAT/bulk:RECORD/bulk:FIELD[@ID = 1]", nsmgr);
Console.WriteLine(fieldElement.Attributes["MAX_LENGTH"].Value);
```

Note that in the above example we needed to use an [`XmlNamespaceManager`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.xmlnamespacemanager.aspx) to specify the namespaces of elements in our xpath expression.  See [HOW TO: Specify Namespaces When You Use an XmlDocument to Execute XPath Queries in Visual C# .NET](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/318545)

For more detail than this you should be able to use one of the many tutorials on xpath and the `XmlDocument` class.

For completeness, here is the same example using the [`XDocument`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.linq.xdocument.aspx) class instead.  For this to work you need to use `using System.Xml.XPath;`.

```
XDocument doc = XDocument.Load("test.xml");

XmlNamespaceManager nsmgr = new XmlNamespaceManager(new NameTable());
nsmgr.AddNamespace("bulk", "http://schemas.microsoft.com/sqlserver/2004/bulkload/format");

XElement fieldElement = (XElement)doc.XPathSelectElement("bulk:BCPFORMAT/bulk:RECORD/bulk:FIELD[@ID = 1]", nsmgr);
Console.WriteLine(fieldElement.Attribute(XName.Get("MAX_LENGTH")).Value);
```

Comment: The OP almost certainly wants to use the __XDocument__ class. XmlDocument is a little dated and harder to use.

Comment: @Henk *really*? At best the usage of `XDocument` is almost identical.  If it ain't broke...

Comment: The usage is only identical if you use the bridging XPath methods. If you use the more native .Elements, .Attribute, .Descendents, etc, it becomes different.